# IIS hosting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

whenever I hosted my application in IIS I used to get error.
I have followed the following steps:

1. InetMgr
2. default web site(right click)
3. add virtual directory
4. physical path
5. selected permissions(read)
6. browse

there I used to get the following error all the time:

```
Server Error in '/evals' Application.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. 
The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.  

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. 

This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off". <!-- Web.Config Configuration File --> 

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web> </configuration>   Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL. <!-- Web.Config Configuration File --> <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web> </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the web.config file for your application and look for the element [`<customerrors>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) under `<system.web>`. If it's not there add it in, and if it is there make sure `mode="Off"`.

When you save the file your app will recycle and you should be presented with a stacktrace of the real error behind this one. You should be able to debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have visual studio attach to the w3wp process hosting your site to step through the code...